# Проект NetStandard не находит библиотеку System.IO.FileSystem

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

В проекте .NET Standard Class Library при любом обращении к типам из пространства имён System.IO возникает исключение:

> Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.

Пару дней назад всё работало. Я, как тётенька из бухгалтерии, ничего не трогал, "оно само".

В Dependencies проекта присутствуют как System.IO, так и System.IO.FileSystem.

Пробовал Clean и Rebuild solution. Пробовал очистить кэш nuget. Бил в бубен. Ничего не помогло.

Сама библиотека вызывается из разных проектов .NET Core (и проектов на классическом .NET - именно с этим возникли проблемы, как оказалось).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело оказалось в следующем.

Если в библиотеке .NET Standard использовать какой-либо nuget-пакет, а потом эту библиотеку использовать в проекте .NET Core, то никаких проблем не возникает.

Но если эту библиотеку использовать в приложении на классическом фреймворке .NET, то нужно тот nuget-пакет подключить и в само это приложение. Хотя напрямую он не используется!