# System.IO.FileLoadException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку

Tags: c#, .net

В чем проблема? Я мучаюсь 4 дня с этой ошибкой. `NetFramework 4.5.2`

Полный код [тут](https://github.com/crosire/scripthookvdotnet/blob/dev_v3/source/core/ScriptDomain.cs)

```
[16:47:00] [DEBUG] Path C:\test\bin\scripts
[16:47:00] [DEBUG] Location C:\test\bin\ScriptHookVDotNet.dll
[16:47:00] [DEBUG] FullName GTA.ScriptDomain
[16:47:00] [ERROR] Failed to create script domain':
System.IO.FileLoadException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "C:\\test\\bin\\ScriptHookVDotNet.dll" либо одну из их зависимостей. Данное имя сборки или база кода недействительны. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131047)
Имя файла: 'C:\\test\\bin\\ScriptHookVDotNet.dll'
   в System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nInit(RuntimeAssembly& assembly, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean raiseResolveEvent)
   в System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.CreateAssemblyName(String assemblyString, Boolean forIntrospection, RuntimeAssembly& assemblyFromResolveEvent)
   в System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   в System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   в System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   в System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   в GTA.ScriptDomain.Load(String path)
```

Конструктор класса:

```
public ScriptDomain()
{
    AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    AppDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(HandleResolve);
    AppDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(HandleUnhandledException);

    CurrentDomain = this;

    _executingThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

    Log("[INFO]", "Created new script domain with v", typeof(ScriptDomain).Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString(3), ".");

    Console = new ConsoleScript();
}
```

Метод:

```
public static ScriptDomain Load(string path)
{
    if (!Path.IsPathRooted(path))
    {
        path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), path);
    }

    path = Path.GetFullPath(path);

    // Create AppDomain
    var setup = new AppDomainSetup();
    setup.ApplicationBase = path;
    setup.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";
    setup.ShadowCopyDirectories = path;

    var appdomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ScriptDomain_" + (path.GetHashCode() * Environment.TickCount).ToString("X"), null, setup, new System.Security.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted));
    appdomain.InitializeLifetimeService();

    Log("[DEBUG]", "Path ", path);
    Log("[DEBUG]", "Location ", typeof(ScriptDomain).Assembly.Location);
    Log("[DEBUG]", "FullName ", typeof(ScriptDomain).FullName);

    ScriptDomain scriptdomain = null;

    try
    {
        //scriptdomain = (ScriptDomain) appdomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(typeof(ScriptDomain).Assembly.Location, typeof(ScriptDomain).FullName);

        var obj = appdomain.CreateInstance(typeof(ScriptDomain).Assembly.Location, typeof(ScriptDomain).FullName);
        scriptdomain = (ScriptDomain) obj.Unwrap();

        //scriptdomain = (ScriptDomain)(appdomain.CreateInstance(typeof(ScriptDomain).Assembly.Location, typeof(ScriptDomain).FullName).Unwrap());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log("[ERROR]", "Failed to create script domain':", Environment.NewLine, ex.ToString());

        AppDomain.Unload(appdomain);

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: (1) А сама сборка `C:\test\bin\ScriptHookVDotNet.dll` лежит на месте? Со всеми зависимостями? (2) Можно из кода убрать всё ненужное?

Comment: Нутром [чую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/707566/184217), что проблема связана с .NET Core / .NET Standard. Ваше приложение под какую платформу?

Comment: @VladD да, она там лежит, пути верно указаны.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, .net 4.5.2

Comment: @Alexander: Окей, а зависимости лежат на месте? Может, `ScriptHookVDotNet.dll` зависит от других сборок?

Comment: @VladD там всего их 3

System, 
System.Drawing, 
System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Хм. Это хуже :) А что говорит fusion log?